# Is the 'subject detection' feature in iOS 16 available through a developer API in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiimage

iOS 16 includes a feature where any [image can be long-pressed](https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/isolate-copy-share-subjects-photos/) to 'cut out' the main subject of the image in an impressive way, Apple calls this 'subject detection' or 'subject isolation'.

Is this capability exposed in the developer APIs anywhere? I see the Vision framework, but it does not seem to be able to do subject detection in this way. Maybe I've missed another framework.

I'd like to programmatically detect the boundary of the subject in a UIImage so that I may apply a visual effect of my own given the boundary of the subject.

Thanks for any advice!